# agreement with inverted sentences

Tags: verbs

> Patients experiencing this syndrome due to drug toxicity is a common occurrence in Asian population.

Please let me know whether the verb should be *is* or *are*.

Comment: Non-finite subject clauses take singular verb agreement. Since the subject in your example is a non-finite clause, it follows that the verb should be singular "is".

Comment: @BillJ I agree, but would add a comma after "toxicity" for clarification.

Comment: But that would violate the prohibition in Present-day English on punctuation separating subject and verb. There are a few exceptions, but this isn't one of them.

Comment: I'd throw it out and start over.  Something like "It is common for members of the Asian population to experience this syndrome due to drug toxicity."  Or, "This syndrome, caused by drug toxicity, is common in the Asian population."

Answer (score 3):

In a comment, BillJ wrote:

> Non-finite subject clauses take singular verb agreement. Since the subject in your example is a non-finite clause, it follows that the verb should be singular "is".

Answer (score -1):

Tricky, but I'd say "is" due to the collective state of the first word.